# How can I handle the package version requirement, when two or more packages are depends on another common library?

Tags: python, numpy, pip, python-packaging

I tried:

```bash
pip3 install "numpy==1.24.1"
```

and

```
pip3 install "numpy==1.24.0"
```

but they both give the same error:

> ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account
> all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of
> the following dependency conflicts. numba 0.56.4 requires
> numpy<1.24,>=1.18, but you have numpy 1.24.2 which is incompatible.

How to solve this?

Comment: The dependancy says `<1.24` it means ***Less Than*** 1.24, but you're trying to use 1.24 (which is equal to, not less than). Have you tried 1.23 or earlier?

Answer (score 1):

As [MatBailie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75673235/how-can-i-handle-the-package-version-requirement-when-two-or-more-packages-are#comment133501273_75673235) suggested, numba==0.56.4 requires numpy's version to be **strictly lower** than 1.24.

However, you are trying to install a version of numpy that is **over or equal** to 1.24 (1.24.0 >= 1.24 and 1.24.1 >= 1.24).

Instead, you should try:

```bash
pip3 install "numpy<1.24,>=1.18"
```

Comment: What about numba version `0.57.1`? Is it compatible with numpy `1.24.0`? @vvvv